# Python Web Scraping Display additional data fields on screen

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, blockchain

Good day. I need help again to do web scraping of the url https://bscscan.com/token/0x15a217c30b1303fbf64b8bdc3323fd3c14e9acb3#balances. There are still data that I wanted to display but cannot figure out how.

```
    import re
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    cotractpage = requests.get("https://bscscan.com/token/0x722126182535a93fb70633ea09c228b43894bf84#balances")
    ca = BeautifulSoup(cotractpage.content, 'html.parser')
    
    #print holders
    tokenholders = ca.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_tokenHolders').get_text()
    tokenholdersa = "Total Holders: " + ((((tokenholders.strip()).strip("Holders:")).strip()).strip(" a ")).strip()
    print(tokenholdersa)
    
    #print transfers -> Not working
    tokentransfers = ca.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_trNoOfTxns').get_text()
    tokentransfersa = "Total Transfers: " + ((((tokentransfers.strip()).strip("Transfers:")).strip()))
    print(tokentransfersa)
    
    #print name
    website = ca.find('span', class_='text-secondary small').get_text()
    tokename = "Name: " + website
    print(tokename)
    
    #print marketcap
    mcapa = ca.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_valuepertoken').get_text()
    print("Market Cap: " + re.search(r'Market Cap.*?([$\d,.]+)', mcapa, flags=re.S).group(1))
    
    #print totalsupply
    totalbox = ca.find('div', class_='col-md-8').get_text().split('(')[0].strip() 
    print("Total Supply: " + totalbox)
    
    #Lock
    lp = ca.find('i', class_='far fa-file-alt text-secondary').get_text()
    print(lp)
```

Needs Help:

1. How to display the total transfers
2. How can I find the row with the icon(Lock) beside and print the percentage
3. How can I find the 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead and return the percentage

   The code above displays:

```
     Total Holders: 6
     Name: FUCKTHEMOON 
     Market Cap: $0.00
     Total Supply: 1,000,000,000,000,000 FUCKTHEMOON

     Total Transfers: 7 <---- Does not work. Needs help
     Lock: 83.5687% <---- Does not work. Needs help
     Burn: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead, 15.0000% <---- Does not work. Needs help
```

Comment: for total transfers you can use direct id of span `totaltxns` &  i not able to see lock or burn   on the page

Comment: the lock or burn is already on the #6 PancakeSwap V2: FUCKTHEMOON 116,181,635.738731337 0.0000%

Comment: table is loading dynamic so you have to use `selenium` for that

Comment: Thank you. How would I know next time that the table is being loaded dynamically?

Comment: if you print `ca.prettify()` it will print full page source which is not matching with chrome developer tool page source , for example  table is present in a div with id of `maintable` when you try to find in beautiful soup is returning `None` so